# Angular default route stopped working when I switched from Linux to Windows Hosting

Tags: angular, .htaccess, angular-ui-router

### **tl;dr:**

When someone visits **mywebsite.com**, the default route should redirect to **mywebsite.com/about**. This doesn't work and my component doesn't load into the routeroutlet.

### **Long version:**

I recently switched from Linux hosting to Windows Hosting.
As a first step, I uploaded my portfolio site which is a pure Angular / Typescript app.

This site worked perfectly on linux, but on windows the default route seems to have stopped working. Here's the routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'about', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'about', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'skills', component: SkillsComponent },
  { path: 'interests', component: InterestsComponent }
];
```

And here's my **.htaccess** file (which I have to use on my windows host because the IIS Rewrite Module isn't installed there):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

So, as I said: The default (about) route doesn't load when I visit my website.
Once I click on any of the routes (via navbar) they load correctly. Refreshing them with F5 also works.

I don't know a thing about RewriteRules or if I can handle this problem with a special Rule.

Comment: An IIS server does not support `.htaccess` style files. Those are specific to the apache http server. Same with those `RewriteRules`, those are part of the apache server's rewriting module and _not_ supported by an IIS server. You certainly can isntall an apache http server on a MS-Windows platform, but the question is: why did you switch at all?

Comment: My windows host provider does support htaccess rewrites. I specifically asked because I needed the Url Rewrite Module and they told me to use htaccess instead.
I switched because I don't want to bother with dreaded PHP backends anymore. I'm in the process of rebuilding my other sites to use a proper ASP.NET Core backend - that's the reason.

Comment: That would mean that you do _not_ use the MS IIS server, but an apache http server. Are you sure that is the case? I understood the contrary from your question. I actually heard that there is some third party add on software to IIS that _claims_ to make IIS behave just like an apache http server. But again you should know of that is what you actually use.

Comment: I'm on Windows Hosting, which means I can't really change anything on the IIS in the background but I do have a web.config file.
The provider doesn't allow the IIS Url Rewrite module though, so he said to use htaccess instead. I don't know how they make that work in the background, but the htaccess rules are working for the most part. Just the default rule is making problems.

Comment: An extremely exotic setup. I hope you won't constantly run into issues with that strange hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me: Like so often I solved the problem *after* posting on SO.

My windows hosting provider applies a basic web.config file for every app I want to host.
So I had a web.config in the IIS root and an additional web.config & .htaccess file in the website's directory.

**I fixed the problem by deleting all web.config files (both from the domain root and website directory) and only leaving the .htaccess file inside the website directory.**